# List all my variables

Tags: bash, variable

I'm just learning the basics, including how to declare and mess around with variables. Is there a simple way to display a list of all the variables I've named? (Everything I've found by searching only talks about environment variables, which may be what I'm looking for, but probably not?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running `declare` itself will give you a list of all the environmental variables **in the current shell**, including those you defined yourself. It will also include any functions, unless you use the `-p` option that skips them, but adds some extra noise.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different types of variables (actually more than that, but in this context just 2), private and exported.

- Private variables are variables which can be used in the shell (or script) but not by programs launched by the shell (or script).
  You can get a list of all variables including exported ones by using `declare`, `typeset`, or `set`. In bash all 3 do the same thing.
- Exported variables can be used by both the shell or programs launched by it.
  You can get a list of exported variables by using `env`.

One key thing to note is when doing things such as this:

```
FOO="bar"
echo "$FOO"
```

`$FOO` is a private/non-exported variable. The shell is actually expanding `$FOO` to `bar` before it passes it to `echo`. So `echo` is actually being called as `echo "bar"`.

---

You can export variables by doing `export FOO`, or `export FOO="bar"`.
Additionally you can export a variable for just a single call to a program by adding the variable at the beginning of the command. For example

```
FOO="bar" cmd1
cmd2
```

`cmd1` will have access to `$FOO` but `cmd2` will not.